# spring propery initialization issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

I have create a service bean and declare variable . Pseudocode :
//one class

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class CustomerService {
  public Map<Long,Boolean> someMap= new HashMap<>(); 
}
```

//caller class

```
@Component
@Path("/maincontroller")
class MainCaller{
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @POST
    @Path("/process")
    public Response processCustomer() {
        try{
        //some processing 
        }finally{
        synchronized (customerService.someMap) { //liee 64
        //do some work on map
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception @liee a
i dont understand this. As far i know spring creates bean after initializing all its properties. and  as i declared someMap with new variable it should not be null. then why it is giving null pointer exception.
ERROR :

> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse
>   mapMappableContainerException SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not
>   be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.hungama.controller.MainCaller.processCustomer(MainCaller.java:64)

//Web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>org.test.controller</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

//SPRING-CONTEXT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <import resource="rest-datasource.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
         <property name="locations">  
               <list>  
               <value>classpath:/retailser_detaults.properties</value>  
               <value>classpath:/log4j.properties</value>  
               </list>  
         </property>  
    </bean>
</beans>
```

//pom.xml

```
<!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Is the MainCaller also a Spring Bean? If so, how do you instantiate it?

Comment: no its not spring bean

Comment: `MainCaller` appears to be a Jersey controller. Have you correctly integrated Spring and Jersey? Please post your `web.xml`

Comment: If it's not a Spring bean, how do you expect the customer service to be autowired? The maincaller needs to be a Spring bean too, to be eligible for autowiring.

Comment: Yes its is jersey controller.And i am properrly getting customerService object as i have checked it using debug. aslo inside customerService i have used other Service bean which are perfectely working.

Comment: @ErikPragt MainController is jersey controller. pls see updated code

Comment: If you are sure `customerService` is not null, where are you getting the NPE? Please post your stacktrace

Comment: You have 2 instances of your `MainCaller` one managed by spring (probably autodetected with component-scanning due to the @Component), properly injected but unused another managed by Jersey not injected and that is the one that is used. Setup spring/jersey integration correctly. See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html and the sample https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.10/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp

Comment: Stack trace saying NPE at `processChanges()` but you are posting `processCustomer()`. Where `processChanges()` method in `MainCaller` class.

Comment: @M.Deinum added web.xml

Comment: @suninsky that is dummy code updated

Comment: @M.Deinum if that is the case that you are saying that 2 instances of MainCaller then code is working fine for ws call as it uses another service bean to do work. so why only property is not initialized properly?

Comment: can you also add your spring context configuration

Comment: Which jersey version are you using? The documentation I sample I pointed you to are using Jersey 2.10 yor configuration points to a 1.x versions.

Comment: Your `MainCaller` has only one property not 2.

Comment: can you try make `someMap` private and give him a getter, and try if it works

Comment: @M.Deinum it have few more property but they are also showing null in debug mode

Comment: There is no need to have `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. It's not the problem, but it does you no good

Comment: hence the 2 instances. Your integration is flawed somewhere...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 using setter and getter it works thanks .But why previously it did not worked.This ans is important to understand behavior of spring ill do some research from my side.Thanks anyways. Thank to all other guys as well

Comment: @M.Deinum i have taken integration reference from MKYONG site (http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to clarify:

**reason**:
1. you are using @Transactional, so you need to understand it works with AOP, see here [Spring transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained).
2. You annotated you service class, which implements no interface, which means spring will use CGLIB to implement transaction management. (If you have an interface, it will use proxy pattern to implement transaction management).
3. CGLIB modifies your byte code of this class, which causes the NPE

**Solution**: use getter/setter pattern to void direct access of public field.

**Misc**: IMO it is not a good practice to use public field. Static cache using map could cause potential memory leak.